# Определение слова в ячейке сканворда — это неполное предложение, включающее сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Определение слова в ячейке сканворда — это неполное предложение, включающее составное именное сказуемое?

> Старинный город на Волге
>   Лиственное дерево
>   Предмет одежды
>   Первый космонавт

Можно ли здесь считать определение неполным предложением? Или это видоизмененная конструкция, характерная для данного случая, где уже нельзя говорить о предложениях и "традиционных" подходах к синтаксическому анализу?